# How to bundle 3D meshes and assets with an addon

Tags: python, objects, add-on

I am thinking about adding 3D objects to my addon, and implementing an "add object" interface that allows a few simple, limited geometrical transformations (like scale width and height).

I wonder what is the preferred way of doing this? I assume I could bundle the zip file of the deployed addon with  anything from obj, ply files, or even use an assets blend file to append the assets. I could even push the vertices and faces info into a json file and load it myself (implementing an operator that reads and creates objects from json).

All of the above options come with development time and performance impacts. I wonder what way I should go, to make the addon simple to implement (and maintain code-wise) and giving good performance (as I might go for very complex models)

Comment: Asset Browser panel now exists in Blender. It would probably be logical to use Blender's existing functionality related to assets. Anyway, the best way to save objects for use in Blender is without question in Blender's native format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future, I would recommend using the Asset Browser, but Blender's current Python API for the Asset Browser is not ready for general use.

In the meantime, I would recommend keeping the objects in a Blend file and using the [library](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html) interface to read objects, materials, or other artifacts from that blend file.

A simple example using this is explained [here](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/appending-all-objects-from-the-external-blend-file-to-the-scene-with-blender-python-api/)